# Is it possible to render multiple tokens in custom content pane?

Tags: panels, tokens

I have created a custom content pane in a Panels layout, so that I can output a part number and short description field side-by-side as one element.  I added the tokens `%node:title` and `%node:body` (the two fields containing the data) and wrapped them in an `<h2>` tag. However, when the page is rendered, it only puts `%node:title` inside the `<h2>` tag and adds the `%node:body` as a separate `<p>` element.

What gives?

Comment: umm, an `H2` tag cannot contain a `P` tag within it. Somewhere in `render()` the malformed HTML you are trying to render is being cleaned up as you you're getting `<h2>title</h2><p>body here</p>` which is valid HTML. So if you try to do something not silly it will work correctly :). Re-think what you're trying to output and how it's displayed.

Comment: What I have entered is `<h2>%node:title %node:body</h2>`. The Panels module appears to be stripping the second token out and adding it after the H2 tag.